# How to archive old orders in Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce, views

I have a site with more than 15000 commerce orders. This is slowing down the site drastically. I have upgraded all the modules and applied the patches regarding the table locking and so on. They haven't been of much help.

I am ok with removing the order history from the site. I just want to keep an archive of that so that I can use them once I have enough resources to handle everything.

I am not able to get the site up. Hence I will have to do all the work from the command line. So is there any safe and suggested way to archive the orders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just backup your database using phpmyadmin, doing a .mysql export of the whole database which would keep record of all orders in the `commerce_order` and `commerce_customer_profile` tables?

Then using phpmyadmin, just remove all rows from the `commerce_order` table, to wipe the slate clean.

In the future, if you wanted to add all orders back into the site, you could import the data from your backup.

Comment: Chris I need the last 100 orders to be kept. So I need to delete the tables in such a way last few orders are not screwed up and they are in sync. I mean they have proper relationship to their customer profile and other related data.

Comment: I see. I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that the table rows commerce_order and commerce_customer_profile both have a customer order number column to reference by. As long as you make sure you are not deleting the last 100 order numbers, its shouldn't be affected.